# Task.WhenAll not resolving in synchronous method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

I have a synchronous method that needs to call multiple times the same http end point with different parameters, wait for all requests to return and process the combined results in a synchronous fashion. Here is the simplified implementation of the synchronous method:

```
public void Test(IEnumerable<int> configs){
    var ratings = Task.WhenAll(configs.Select(x=>Rate(x)));

    ratings.Wait();

    // More work done once all Rate tasks are complete
    var test = ratings.Result.Select(x=>....);
}
```

And the simplified implementation of the Rate method is as follows:

```
private async Task<JToken> Rate(int arg){

    var content = CreateContent(arg);

    var uri = "http://fake.com/foo/bar";
    var requestUri = new Uri(uri);

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content))
        {
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JToken>();
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to verify that the http requests are getting posted asynchronously the way I want, however, I never get past `ratings.Wait()`. The status of `ratings` is always WaitingForActivation with `Result` showing Not yet computed. I am unsure about what is happening here.

Is wrapping the `client` and the `response` in `using` statements with `await` causing them to be disposed of before the method can return? If I call `.Result` in the `Rate` method, I get past the `ratings.Wait()`, but then http calls are made synchronously, which defeats the whole purpose.

EDIT:

As suggested below, I used Task.WaitAll, unfortunately with the same result. It looks like the individual `Rate` tasks are not resolving although I can see that I am receiving a 200 Http Code as a response in fiddler.

```
public void Test(IEnumerable<int> configs){
    var tasks = configs.Select(x => Rate(x)).ToArray();

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    var ratings = tasks.Select(x => x.Result);

    // More work done once all Rate tasks are complete
    var test = ratings.Result.Select(x=>....);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a deadlock.  The `PostAsync` completion callbacks are sent to your thread's event queue, which will get processed only after your current function returns to the main event loop.  Since you're not returning until the completion does its thing... deadlock.

You can avoid this by starting the Tasks on the thread pool.  You can request completion callbacks on the thread pool via `GetAwaiter().ConfigureAwait(false)`, but this has to be done on each Task, not just the composite Task, or the Task returned by an `async` function.  Better to launch the whole `async` function on the thread pool using `Task.Run` so that its subtasks automatically have affinity to the threadpool and not your UI thread.

Comment: how you have guessed that is an UI thread and not a back-end asp task

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel: From the symptom "I never get past `ratings.Wait()`"

Comment: @Ben Voigt, not a UI thread but a WebApi context. However, this is the same problem. Additional resources: a very good blog post from Stephen Clearly on the subject http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: While you *can* run these on background threads, that will negatively impact the scalability of your web service. It would be much better to make `Test` asynchronous and use `await`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any experience with using `Task.WhenAll`, but you should be able to simply `await` for the task collection to be completed. Like this:

```
public async void Test(IEnumerable<int> configs){
    var ratings = await Task.WhenAll(configs.Select(x=>Rate(x)));

    // More work done once all Rate tasks are complete
    var test = ratings.Select(x=>....);
}
```

I'm currently not able to try it out myself, unfortunately.

Comment: That would require the `Test` method to be `async`.